# How can I remove the first directory from the include path in bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-cpp

I have the following project structure that I am trying to move to Bazel from another build system:

```
MyProject/
├─ WORKSPACE.bazel
├─ app/
│  ├─ BUILD.bazel
│  ├─ main.cpp
├─ lib/
│  ├─ BUILD.bazel
│  ├─ lib1/
│  │  ├─ lib1.hpp
│  │  ├─ lib1.cpp
│  ├─ lib2/
│  │  ├─ lib2.hpp
│  │  ├─ lib2.cpp
├─ etc/
├─ test/
```

I have managed to get the project to compile but have had to change the include paths and the rest of my team is not happy with this, though they do enjoy the improved build performance. I'm looking to return the include paths back to what they were before, currently I have the project compiling with:

```
#include "lib/lib1/lib1.hpp"
#include "lib/lib2/lib2.hpp"
```

in `main.cpp` but the rest of the team really wants to go back to:

```
#include "lib1/lib1.hpp"
#include "lib2/lib2.hpp"
```

and my BUILD files to move to Bazel haven't required anything crazy either:

`app/BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "MyApp",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = [
        ...,
    ],
    linkopts = [
        ...,
    ],
    deps = [
        "//lib:lib1",
        "//lib:lib2",
    ],
)
```

`lib/BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "lib1",
    hdrs = glob(["lib1/**/*.hpp"]),
    srcs = glob(["lib1/**/*.cpp"]),
    copts = [
        ...,
    ],
    linkopts = [
        ...,
    ],
    visibility = [
        "//app:__pkg__",
        "//test:__pkg__",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib2",
    hdrs = glob(["lib2/**/*.hpp"]),
    srcs = glob(["lib2/**/*.cpp"]),
    copts = [
        ...,
    ],
    linkopts = [
        ...,
    ],
    visibility = [
        "//app:__pkg__",
        "//test:__pkg__",
    ],
)
```

Is this not possible using Bazel or is there something that I've missed?

Comment: You should be able to use https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library.includes. That is `includes = ["lib1/"]` on the `cc_library()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Can you write it as an answer and I will accept it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the includes on the library to "." worked:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "lib1",
    hdrs = glob(["lib1/**/*.hpp"]),
    srcs = glob(["lib1/**/*.cpp"]),
    includes = ["."],
    copts = [
        ...,
    ],
    linkopts = [
        ...,
    ],
    visibility = [
        "//app:__pkg__",
        "//test:__pkg__",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib2",
    hdrs = glob(["lib2/**/*.hpp"]),
    srcs = glob(["lib2/**/*.cpp"]),
    includes = ["."],
    copts = [
        ...,
    ],
    linkopts = [
        ...,
    ],
    visibility = [
        "//app:__pkg__",
        "//test:__pkg__",
    ],
)
```